Jakarta faces issue: DI is not available
I am upgrading java to v17 and some servers to the latest versions of jakarta faces. When I start my server, I'm getting an error that I could use some help with...
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getCdiBeanManager(Util.java:1534)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3976)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4403)

I can't find a good answer about why I'm getting this error and have been struggling with it for several days now. Would anyone know how to resolve this?
Here are some details:

java v17
tomcat v11

This is some of my classpath:

jakarta.faces-4.1.2.jar
jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api-4.1.0.jar
jakarta.enterprise.cdi-el-api-4.1.0.jar

Is there any other information that would be relevant to share?

From the error it requires a CDI implementation, such as Weld or Apache OpenWebBeans.
<!-- Weld for CDI support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${weld.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Check my Jakarta EE 9 servlet template project, which provides the essential dependencies for Apache Tomcat and Eclipse Jetty when starting a Servlet container-based application, including Faces, REST support.

Thanks for the response! There isn't a lot of information out there on how this works. I was able to use the wed-servlet-shaded-6.0.0.CR2.jar.
